# Meta Quest 2 - Unity app, graphics have very low resolution

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm doing an app in Unity3D for Meta Quest 2 headsets. I've imported some interior model with materials and textures, but when I run the app on glasses it has really poor resolution. I don't know what is that happening and how can I change that. Screenshot below. Surely we can have a better quality of image on Quest 2.

Any advices are welcome!

[image: screenshot from the app]

Answer (score 0):

Basically quest 2 is not a really powerful headset. it has the same capability like a mid range smartphone.
Don't get me wrong though. you do can improve the graphic quality by using 4k texture with post processing. And it will up the graphic by a lot.

However since the performance will surely be suffer, you may need to be "smart" to manage it. For example by reducing draw calls as much as possible or even using low resolution texture but a lot of UV stacking.

Hopefully you got the idea. :)